# Show that $a^2+8bc=(2b+c)^2$ if $a,b$ and $c$ form an arithmetic progression

Tags: sequences-and-series

The numbers $a,b$ and $c$ form an arithmetic progression. Show that $a^2+8bc=(2b+c)^2.$ Can we say that $a,b$ and $c$ form an ap if $a^2+8bc=(2b+c)^2?$

We have that $2b=a+c$ (we know that a sequence is an arithmetic progression iff $a_n=\dfrac{a_{n-1}+a_{n+1}}{2}\text{   } \forall \text{   }n\ge2$). I am stuck here and I would be very grateful if you could give me a hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the RHS, you don't have $a$.

So using $a=  2b -c$,

$\begin{align}a^2+8bc &= (2b-c)^2+8bc \\&= (2b)^2\color{blue}{- 2(2b)(c)}+c^2+\color{blue}{8bc} \\&= (2b)^2+\color{blue}{2(2b)(c)}+c^2 \\&= (2b+c)^2\end{align}$

---

Edit: Just now saw the second part
If $a^2+8bc = (2b+c)^2$, then

$\begin{align}a^2 + 8bc = (4b^2)+8bc +c^2 &\Rightarrow a^2 = 4b^2-4bc+c^2 = (2b-c)^2 \\&\Rightarrow a = \pm(2b-c) \\&\Rightarrow b = \frac{a+c}{2} \text{ or } b = \frac{c-a}{2}\end{align}$

So, they may or may not be in AP.

For example take, $1,3,5$ they are in AP and satisfy $1^2 = (2(3) -5)^2$

But $-1,3,5$ are not in AP even when they satisfy the condition $(-1)^2 = (2(3)-5)^2 = 1$

Comment: Take $x = a$ and $y = 2b-c$. So $x^2 = y^2\Rightarrow x^2-y^2 = 0 \Rightarrow (x+y)(x-y) = 0$ So either $x = y$ or $x = -y$

Answer (score 2):

WLOG $a=b-d, c=b+d$

$$2b+c=2b+b+d=?$$

$$a^2+8bc=(b-d)^2+8b(b+d)=\cdots=(3b+d)^2=(2b+\underbrace{b+d})^2$$

Alternatively,

$$a^2+8bc=(2b+c)^2$$

$$\iff a^2=4b^2-4bc+c^2=(2b-c)^2$$

So, we need

either $a=2b-c\iff a+c=2b$   i.e., $a,b,c$ are in A.P.

or $a=-(2b-c)\iff 2b=c-a$  i.e., $c,b,-a$ are in A.P.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I appreciate it. Okay if we know that $a^2+8bc=(2b+c)^2$ is true, we can say that $a^2=(2b-c)^2.$ How did you make the next conclusions? I don't understand.

Comment: Why when $2b=c-a$ then $c,b,-a$ are in A.P.?

Comment: @nicoledobreva,  If $c,b,-a$ are in A.P. $$\dfrac{c+(-a)}2= b$$  right?

Comment: @nicoledobreva, For the first question, just transpose $8bc$ to the other side

Comment: Oh, thank you! I see it now. So if the equality holds $a,b$ and $c$ aren't in A.P. always, right?

Comment: Can you give me an example? Thanks!

Comment: @nicoledobreva, Clearly, $a,b,c$ in A.P. is a sufficient condition for the proposition, never necessary  right?  $$2b=c-a$$ will also satisfy the proposition

Comment: Thank you. Can you just explain to me how do we solve for $a$ the equation $a^2=(2b-c)^2?$

Comment: @nicoledobreva, Use $$x^2-y^2=(x+y)(x-y)$$